# Unexpected output using tikz/textpos

Tags: tikz-pgf, textpos

The following code (MWE)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{4}[0,0](1.3,2.5)
\begin{center}
SOME TITLE TEXT SOME TITLE TEXT\\
SOME TITLE TEXT SOME TITLE TEXT
\end{center}
\end{textblock}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{} \clearpage  %flush this page

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw] (20mm,150mm) -- (20mm,250mm);
  \path[draw] (100mm,150mm) -- (100mm,250mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

is expected to produce two pages;

the first one containing eg some title text and the second one two parallel lines.

Instead in the second page the first one is appended (take a look at the picture)

[image]

I am using `pdflatex` from MikTeX 2.9 (updated) and compiling with `-enable-write18`.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you viewing the pdf-file in "book mode", i.e. showing two facing sides at once?

Comment: yes I did it to get the screenshot (the problem appears even when not viewing two sides at once)

Comment: I needed to comment out the `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz-external/]` line to get this to compile,  after which the second page only had the vertical lines.

Comment: Yes, when tikz externalize is removed it works fine. But I need the externalization. As for not compiling maybe its because of `-enable-write18` (I think that when you are not using miktex its `-shell-escape`).

Comment: Hmmmm. You are correct. With `\tikzexternalize` I do see the behavior you describe.  Needed to remove `[prefix=tikz-external/]` to get it to compile.

Comment: Oh yes I should be removing it also from the MWE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that both `textpos` package and `externalize` library play games with TeX shipout mechanism.

Supposedly, `externalize` should ignore all text outside of the `tikzpicture` environments, which includes the text in the `textblock` environment. However, `textpos` in `absolute` mode includes this text inside a box which is shipped at the end of the page, apparently without tikz knowing it, and thus interfering in the "page" that `externalize` is trying to build.

The hack I've found is to empty this `textpos` box after using it. In this particular example, the following MWE works, but I don't know if it is general enough. Try it in your actual use case and tell us.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\makeatletter
\def\cleartextposbox{\global\setbox\TP@holdbox\vbox{}}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{4}[0,0](1.3,2.5)
\begin{center}
SOME TITLE TEXT SOME TITLE TEXT\\
SOME TITLE TEXT SOME TITLE TEXT
\end{center}
\end{textblock}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\newpage\cleartextposbox   % <----- 

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[draw] (20mm,150mm) -- (20mm,250mm);
 \path[draw] (100mm,150mm) -- (100mm,250mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: awesome, tested in the actual case and the series of corrupted figures is now fixed... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your answer works also in complex beamer environments, where `textblock` is commonly used in custom *beameroutertheme* etc., BUT: rather then putting `\cleartextposbox` behind the textblock (within the theme definition), it should be put before the tikz-figure due to externalize. Thank you very much, I already lost my hair on this problem ;)

Comment: @JLDiaz Thanks for this analysis. Another way to evade the problem is to use textpos in _relative_ mode, where it doesn't use `\shipout`; if the `{textblock}` appears at a more-or-less predictable place, then this should allow control of the positioning at the cost of a little more mental arithmetic, and without confusing TikZ. I'll adjust the textpos docs to discuss this problem.